# Busca de filtro não funciona

Tags: php, mysqli

Tenho um form que passa os dados da consulta e um arquivo externo em PHP chamado `busca.php`

Meu problema é que não recebo nenhum erro php para saber o problema de ele não achar a busca de filtro. Quando uso a busca normal ele me retorna todos os valores do banco.

O que esta acontecendo? Segue o código do programa, onde `q` é pra receber o campo de texto `consulta` de um arquivo `consulta.php`:

```
if(isset($_POST['buscar'])){
    $q = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
    $query_Busca = "SELECT * FROM equipamento WHERE tombamento LIKE '%$q%'";
    $Busca = mysqli_query($con,$query_Busca) or die($con->error);
    // Check results
    if($Busca){
        //Se for um sucesso!
        $row_Busca = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Busca);
        $totalRows_Busca = $Busca->num_rows;
    }
```

Neste `else` a função esta funcionando normal dando todos os dados do banco como desejo o problema esta mesmo no código acima onde quero achar o equipamento somente pelo numero de tombamento que fica em "consulta" contudo ele não acha e não me retorna erro.

```
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM equipamento";
    $Busca = $con->query($query) or die($con->error);
    $row_Busca = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Busca);
    $totalRows_Busca = $Busca->num_rows;
}
```

Comment: Veja se `$_POST['busca`] tem algum valor e verifique se a consulta retorna algo, pode dar: `print_r($row_Busca);`

Comment: eu coloquei e nao me retorno nada @perdeu, não apareceu nada, esta certo isso?

Comment: Se eu colocar desta forma no if `$row_Busca = $Busca->fetch_assoc($Busca);` funciona, mas ele me da esse erro: ` mysqli_result::fetch_assoc() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1`

Comment: Não sei se ajuda, mas o `tombamento` é do tipo INT ou seja, somente numero, esta certo o LIKE que eu coloquei? O que me deixa curioso é que não da erro nenhum.

Comment: Like não funciona com campos int.

Comment: o que uso para comparar entao?

Answer (score 1):

tente padronizar o seu código, pois em uma parte você usa funções mysqli_ e em outra usa objetos, e esses detalhes acabam causando dor de cabeça e dificuldades em encontrar os problemas.

copiando do bloco que está funcionando, ficaria assim:

(obs.: se o campo tombamento é int, use (int) para converter para inteiro no lugar do like.)

```
if(isset($_POST['buscar'])){
    $q = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM equipamento WHERE tombamento = '" . (int)$q . "'";
    $Busca = $con->query($query) or die($con->error);
    // Check results
    if($Busca){
        //Se for um sucesso!
        $row_Busca = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Busca);
        $totalRows_Busca = $Busca->num_rows;
    }
```

Comment: mas fiquei na duvida sobre essas variáveis `$_POST['buscar']` e `$_POST['consulta']` porque você condiciona com a 'buscar' e utiliza a 'consulta'?

Comment: Busca é um botão, o consulta é o campo com o numero. Testei e não funcionou, quero deixar tudo com MYSQLi, se souber como eu arrumo para deixar tudo MYSQLi agradeço também.

Comment: "não funcionou" é muito vago, você consegue determinar o que ele esta fazendo? adicione um `echo $query;` logo abaixo da `$query = "SELECT ...` e veja se ele vai imprimir a query corretamente com o numero que você digitou, então copie a query e teste-a no phpmyadmin... ou seja se o php não esta lhe dando as mensagens de erro, busque formas de depurar por si mesmo.

Comment: ele me imprimiu: SELECT * FROM `equipamento` WHERE `tombamento` LIKE '%458791%'

Comment: você ainda esta usando o like no campo INT, veja no código acima que eu modifique essa parte...

Comment: modifiquei isso e ele nao me da echo no resultado. imprimi o seu select todo e nada de erro. SELECT * FROM `equipamento` WHERE `tombamento` = '(int)458791' esse numero foi o valor que inseri para achar no Mysql que se encontra la.

Comment: Tentei fazer uma modificação direta e achei essa mensagem agora, o que pode ser? SELECT * FROM `equipamento` WHERE `tombamento` = `458791`Unknown column 'tombamento' in 'where clause'

Comment: O pior agora é que resolvi esse colocando assim: $row_Busca = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_Busca); Ele acha mas me retorna com erro de PHP:  Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given

Comment: Não existe uma coluna chamada tombamento na sua tabela equipamento... Verifique.

Comment: eu consegui, era soh tirar essa parte do codigo: ` $row_Busca = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Busca);` que funcionou! Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.